# ImportError: No module named skfmm

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nvidia-digits

I am trying to install "DIGITS" in a virtual environment, I am receiving the following error:

```
digits/webapp.py:7: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.socketio is deprecated, use flask_socketio instead.
  from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py:93: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.wtf is deprecated, use flask_wtf instead.
  result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):

    import skfmm
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named skfmm
```

Edited: After installing `pip install scikit-fmm`. The following error appeared:

```
digits/webapp.py:7: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.socketio is deprecated, use flask_socketio instead.
  from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py:93: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.wtf is deprecated, use flask_wtf instead.
  result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  ...
    exc_class, code = self._get_exc_class_and_code(code_or_exception)
  File "/home/ss/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1104, in _get_exc_class_and_code
    exc_class = default_exceptions[exc_class_or_code]
KeyError: 300
```

Comment: try to install `skfmm` module first

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan could you please tell me how to install it? Thanks

Comment: `pip install scikit-fmm`

Comment: Thanks I installed

Comment: your problem solved?. But you forgot to ask how i get to know about the problem.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan   now giving another error :(     How did you know about the problem?

Comment: add the new error detail below the previous error so that i can check

Comment: At the bottom of your error report it is telling you there are no module name `skfmm` . that means install it

Comment: check this link this is similar to your problem https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/926

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan thanks for your help. I could install it finally. I installed flask by `conda install Flask==0.10.1` not by `pip`. No DIGITS is working

Answer (score 0):

As Ankur Jyoti Phukan said you should install the package with the command

```
pip install scikit-fmm
```

You may need to add the `--user` flag at the end depending on the permissions of your system.